# the touchpad stops working

Tags: touchpad, lenovo

The touchpad stops working some time after the start of use. Only rebooting fix it.

laptop LENOVO IdeaPad 720S-13ARR

Ubuntu version

```
4.13.0-37-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 7 14:13:23 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

$: cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep MSFT

```
N: Name="MSFT0001:00 04F3:3095 Touchpad"
P: Phys=i2c-MSFT0001:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/AMDI0010:00/i2c-0/i2c-MSFT0001:00/0018:04F3:3095.0001/input/input9
```

grep -i Touchpad /var/log/Xorg.0.log.old

```
[     6.510] (II) config/udev: Adding input device MSFT0001:00 04F3:3095 Touchpad (/dev/input/event7)
[     6.510] (**) MSFT0001:00 04F3:3095 Touchpad: Applying InputClass "libinput touchpad catchall"
[     6.510] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'MSFT0001:00 04F3:3095 Touchpad'
[     6.512] (**) MSFT0001:00 04F3:3095 Touchpad: always reports core events
[     6.512] (II) event7  - (II) MSFT0001:00 04F3:3095 Touchpad: (II) is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
[     6.512] (II) event7  - (II) MSFT0001:00 04F3:3095 Touchpad: (II) device is a touchpad
[     6.513] (II) event7  - (II) MSFT0001:00 04F3:3095 Touchpad: (II) device removed
[     6.513] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "MSFT0001:00 04F3:3095 Touchpad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 13)
[     6.513] (**) MSFT0001:00 04F3:3095 Touchpad: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[     6.513] (**) MSFT0001:00 04F3:3095 Touchpad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[     6.513] (**) MSFT0001:00 04F3:3095 Touchpad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[     6.514] (II) event7  - (II) MSFT0001:00 04F3:3095 Touchpad: (II) is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
[     6.514] (II) event7  - (II) MSFT0001:00 04F3:3095 Touchpad: (II) device is a touchpad
[     6.514] (II) config/udev: Adding input device MSFT0001:00 04F3:3095 Touchpad (/dev/input/mouse1)
[   112.265] (II) event7  - (II) MSFT0001:00 04F3:3095 Touchpad: (II) device removed
```

How i can fix this?